# Downsampling data, grouped by different time periods, into one measurement

Tags: influxdb

My version of influxdb is 0.11. Imagine the situation, I have a "cpu" measurement and want to downsample it. More specifically, I want to downsample it twice, grouping by 10 and 30 minutes. What's more it'll be great to store these new time series in one measurement (say, cpu_aggregated). For this purpose I need to introduce new tag "period". And my new time series should have different values of this tag (10 and 30). Is it possible to implement such schema in influxdb?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, it's not possible at the moment. So, in order to implement such a scenario one should encode the downsampling period into the measurement name:

```
SELECT SUM(count) INTO cpu_aggregated_10 FROM cpu WHERE time < now() GROUP BY time(10m)
SELECT SUM(count) INTO cpu_aggregated_30 FROM cpu WHERE time < now() GROUP BY time(30m)
```

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/influxdb/Q47ly6gxybg.

Answer (score 0):

It's entirely possible.

You'll need to have a [Continuous Query](https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v0.8/api/continuous_queries/) for each possible value for the `period` tag.

If your data comes in at a regular interval, you might want to consider using downsampling into 10 minute groupings and just issue a query that groups by 30 minutes to get the results you're looking for (rather than storing twice the amount of data). You'll also need a retention policy to expire your old data.

As an alternative to using Continuous Queries, you may want to consider using [Kapacitor](https://github.com/influxdata/kapacitor) to downsample the data. Using Kapacitor will also allow you to do more complex things when downsampling.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Could you provide the example of how to specify the tag for destination measurement within cq?

Comment: If you can give me the initial structure of your schema I can help you make the CQs.

Comment: Just realized partially my answer is wrong. Its not possible with CQs but is possible with Kapacitor.